# How to check log4net log path?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

My configuration file is :

```
<log4net  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <appender name="InfoFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="D:/" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd&quot;.txt&quot;" />
            <rollingStyle value="Date" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
            <datePattern value="YYYY-MM-DD'.log'"/>
            <maximumFileSize value="1024KB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="false" />
            <encoding value="utf-8"/>           
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
                <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
                <param name="LevelMax" value="INFO" />
            </filter>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger  - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="ErrorFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="D:/" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10240KB" />
            <datePattern value="YYYY-MM-DD'.log'"/>
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <encoding value="utf-8"/>
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
                <param name="LevelMin" value="WARN" />
                <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
            </filter>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="INFO" />
            <appender-ref ref="InfoFileAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="ErrorFileAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
```

in app.config.

But it has no log file in disk D:!!!!

Comment: Side note - you have two appenders configured to write to exactly same file. Is it by intent?

Comment: have you tried to actually give a path with a file name like D:/myLog.log not just D:/?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky  Yes, i am intend to two type of info in the same file

Comment: @Tobias I've tried give the specify file name like D:/a.log,but it still not work

Comment: Post code where you initialize your logger. log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch

Comment: It seems a bit odd that you tell the appenders to log INFO and WARN/FATAL while in the root you tell them to log only INFO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just verified your config - works fine. You probably didn't initialize log4net properly. You should add into *AssemblyInfo.cs* file:

```
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Or you can use [XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch_overload_1.html) method or simply

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Unlike NLog, log4net cannot initialize itself.

*NOTES*: You should change your date pattern to `yyyy-MM-dd'.log'` - year and day should be lowercase letters. Also you can write several levels with single appender. There is no need to create two appenders which write to same file.

Answer (score 2):

Try as below

```
<file value="D:/ABC.txt" />
```

assemblyinfo.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "~\\Abc\\xyz\\log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```